# Strange behavior while counting NAs, NANs and Inf's

Tags: r, date, dataframe, nan, tibble

I wrote a small function that would count the number of NA, NaN an Inf in a tibble data frame as follows:

```
check.for.missing.values <- function(df) {
     return(  sum(is.na(as.matrix(df)) & !is.nan(as.matrix(df))) +    #NAs
              sum(is.infinite(as.matrix(df))) +                       #Infs
              sum(is.nan(as.matrix(df)))                              #NaNs
)}
```

I tested it with the following tibble:

```
x1 <- tibble(x = 1:7, 
             y = c(NA,NA,Inf,Inf,Inf,-Inf,-Inf), 
             z = c(-Inf,-Inf,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN))
x1
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  x     y     z
<int> <dbl> <dbl>
  1     1    NA  -Inf
  2     2    NA  -Inf
  3     3   Inf   NaN
  4     4   Inf   NaN
  5     5   Inf   NaN
  6     6  -Inf   NaN
  7     7  -Inf   NaN`
```

And I get

```
check.for.missing.values(x1)
[1] 14
```

which of course is the correct answer.

Now, if the tibble that I pass on to the function happens to include observations in date format, then the functions stops working and I can't figure out why:

```
x2 <- mutate(x1, date = as.Date('01/07/2008','%d/%m/%Y'))
x2

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  x     y     z       date
<int> <dbl> <dbl>     <date>
  1     1    NA  -Inf 2008-07-01
  2     2    NA  -Inf 2008-07-01
  3     3   Inf   NaN 2008-07-01
  4     4   Inf   NaN 2008-07-01
  5     5   Inf   NaN 2008-07-01
  6     6  -Inf   NaN 2008-07-01
  7     7  -Inf   NaN 2008-07-01`

check.for.missing.values(x2)
[1] 7
```

Any clues as to what's going on?

Thanks

reyemarr

Comment: See what `as.matrix(x2)` produces and you'll understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nicola mentions, your issue is in the fact that you're converting the data frame to a matrix. In doing so, you force every "cell" to coerce to a single class, in this case that ends up being "character" class, and your `Inf` and `-Inf` are no longer caught by your function.

You can do what you're trying to do without resorting to the matrix conversion, by `apply`ing over the columns in the data frame. In your case, `sapply` will work.

```
check.for.missing.values <- function(df) {
    sum( sapply( df, function(x) {
        sum( { is.na(x) & !is.nan(x) } |
                 is.infinite(x) |
                 is.nan(x) )
    } ) )
}
```

`sapply` iterates over every column, adding up all the occurrences matching the set of given conditions. that returns a numeric vector, which can then be `sum`d again to get the total.

```
check.for.missing.values(x2)
[1] 14
```

Comment: Or just `check.for.missing.values <- function(df) {  x <- unlist(df) ; sum(c((is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)), is.infinite(x), is.nan(x))) }`.

Comment: @ulfelder interesting, I thought `unlist` would coerce to `character` just like `as.matrix`, but it goes to `numeric` instead. What's the difference between `as.matrix` and `unlist` causing that difference?

Comment: Yeah, actually, I just tested my version on a tibble with strings, and then you're back to your original problem. I think it worked with the dates because they could be coerced to numeric, but otherwise `unlist` is going to present problems similar to `as.matrix`. So `sapply` is a more robust solution.

Comment: True. Still interested in why `unlist` and `as.matrix` coerce the same data frame to different classes though.